# what is "SASS" short for?

Tags: cuda

what is "SASS" short for ?

I know it is an asembly level native code ISA targeting specific hardware,
exits in between PTX code and binary code.
but anyone could kindly tell me what does each character stands for ?

all that i can find about Fermi hardware native instruction is in cuobjdump.pdf, but it only gives their names, where can I find more information such as their throughput or latency or IPC or CPI, undertaking units corresponding to each intruction, like SFU, FPU ?

Comment: Search asfermi, if you're interested in some real ISA coding and some benchmarking.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's unrelated to programming. Really, it is.

Answer (score 29):

Streaming ASSembler.... I should know since I invented the term, lead the core team G80 streaming process architecture team and developed first SASS assembler ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Since there seems to be no information on this anywhere, I can only guess: Shader ASSembly language

Answer (score 4):

SASS (as Ashwin points out probably "Shader ASSembly") *is* the binary code that runs on the metal of Fermi architecture devices. What `cudaobjdump` (and older third party tools like [`decuda`](https://github.com/laanwj/decuda/wiki) and [`nv50dis`](http://0x04.net/cgit/index.cgi/nv50dis)) show is a direct disassembly of the cubin payload emitted by the `ptxas` assembler.

<strike>To the best of my knowledge there is no open instruction set documentation for any NVIDIA GPUs.</strike>

At some point during the CUDA 5 release cycle, NVIDIA began to provide a summary document which annotates the basic instruction set of suported GPUs (Fermi, Kepler, and Maxwell as of CUDA 7).

Comment: thank you all, a cuda forum fellow gives the answer from nvdia docs, "http://developer.download.nvidia.com/GTC/PDF/1062_Satoor.pdf", SASS means "Source and Assembly".

Comment: user1282426: That was a useful PDF on debugging. But, I think you might be mistaken by the English used there. What is meant by "source and assembly (SASS) level debugging" is that you can debug both at source code and assembly code levels. And the SASS there refers to assembly, not "source and assembly" together.

Comment: @user1282426: I agree with ashwin's interpretation - you have been misled.

Answer (score 1):

Streaming ASSembly? Since NVIDIA calls their cores, "Streaming Multiprocessors".